# Teradata Date format converion from varchar to date

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I'm stucked somewhere in Teradata date conversion. Can anyone please help, thanks in advance.

Table name is Test2
Table attributes are defined as:

```
Acct_id    Integer,
Date_num   Varchar(10) Character set Latin not casespecific
```

Sample Data:

```
Acct_id   date_num
 234124 2012-03-04
 342123 2021-04-06
```

When trying to cast date_num in date format getting **error**: **Invalid date**

Tried below query:
*Select Acct_id, to_date(Date_num, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DT FROM ACCT_LOAD.TEST2*

I want the date to be in correct date format so I can load to another table where column attributes are defined as date.

Comment: There seems to be some bad data. Try `Select Acct_id, Date_num FROM ACCT_LOAD.TEST2 where trycast(date_num as date) is null and date_num is not null` to find the bad rows.

Comment: @dnoeth trycast I tried and I think it is not working with my client's windows current version. I'm using Teradata 16.20.